# Changing values of a data.frame by indexing on values in two external lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` like so

```
df1<- read.table(text="  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
            0  0 -1 0 0
            -1 0  0  -1  0
            0  0  0  0  0", header=TRUE)
```

and two lists, like so

```
list1<- list()
list1[1]<-4
list1[2]<- list(c(2,5))
list1[3]<- 0

list2<- list()
list2[1]<- 3
list2[2]<- list(c(1,4))
list2[3]<- 0
```

What I want to do is to use list1 to select columns from df1. These will then have to be changed based on the values of columns selected by using list2.

So, for example: when the first element of list1 is selected, the first row's 4th column will be selected. Simultaneously, the first element of list2 will be selected, to extract the value of first row's 3rd column. In the end, df[1,4] will be replaced by df[1,3].

The final data.frame will be as follows

```
  X1  X2  X3  X4  X5
1  0   0  -1  -1   0
2 -1  -1   0  -1  -1
3  0   0   0   0   0
```

I have been attempting on my own since a day, but I cannot figure out how to deal with lists even after reading similar questions here on SO.

Comment: My attempt, if somebody would like to have a laugh or a smile:

mapply(FUN=myFunc,i=seq_along(list1),x=lapply(list1,print),y=lapply(list2,print))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a pretty straightforward use case for a for-loop, given that you're trying to assign:

```
df2 <- df1
for(i in 1:length(list1)){
    if(!list1[[i]]==0 & !list2[[i]]==0) # deal with `0`'s
        df2[i,list1[[i]]] <- df1[i,list2[[i]]]
}
df2
```

Which will give you this:

```
> df2
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  0  0 -1 -1  0
2 -1 -1  0 -1 -1
3  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should have stated two things:
1. Where 0s are encountered, I simply ignore the row, and
2. I am trying to make do without loops, as my data.frames are huge... Unless there is no alternative..

Comment: See edit regarding 1. Regarding 2, `mapply` and similar are still loops, they're just prettier.

Comment: Oh! I didn't realise about the mapply. Well, thank you. I couldn't ask for more, so I am going to practice on my own to see if there is a vectorised solution. I must catch up with you useRs in knowledge of programming!

Answer (score 1):

A crazy `mapply` solution which probably just highlights that sometimes a `for` loop is fine:

```
t(
  data.frame(
    mapply(
        function(l1,l2,sq) {
          if(all(l1==0) & all(l2==0)) 
            {df1[sq,]} else 
            {df1[sq,l1] <- df1[sq,l2]; df1[sq,]}
        },
        list1,
        list2,
        seq_along(list1)
      )
  )
)
```

Result:

```
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
X1 0  0  -1 -1 0 
X2 -1 -1 0  -1 -1
X3 0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution; it does help see why for is OK in this case.